# Angular - Setting Variable results in error?

Tags: angular, variables

I've been working hard on a program today and have come to a problem where I get an error. I'm just trying to take the number that I get for the variable selectedEmployee and use it in an array to find a specific field in that index. I feel as if i'm doing it right but whenever I run it, in the browser, I get an error that says: "Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined"

Here's my tracker.component.ts:

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { PTODataService } from './pto-data.service';
import { PTOData } from './pto-data';
import { EmpInfoService } from './emp-info.service';
import { EmpInfo } from './emp-info'; 

@Component({
    selector: 'pto-tracker',
    templateUrl: `./tracker.component.html`,
    styleUrls: ['./tracker.component.css']
})

export class TrackerComponent implements OnInit{
    empInfo: EmpInfo[];
    ptoData: PTOData[];
    isHidden: boolean = false;
    public selectedEmployee: number = 0;
    public EmpKey: number = this.empInfo[this.selectedEmployee].EmpKey;

    constructor(
        private empInfoService: EmpInfoService,
        private ptoDataService: PTODataService) { }

    getEmpInfo(): void {
        this.empInfoService.getEmpInfos().then(
            empInfo => this.empInfo = empInfo
        );
    }

    getPTOData(): void {
        this.ptoDataService.getPTODatas().then(
            ptoData => this.ptoData = ptoData
        );
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.getEmpInfo();
        this.getPTOData();
    }

    toggleSummary(): void {
        this.isHidden = !this.isHidden;
    }

    nextEmployee(): void {
        this.selectedEmployee = this.selectedEmployee+1;
    }

    previousEmployee(): void {
        this.selectedEmployee = this.selectedEmployee-1;
    }
}
```

here's my tracker.component.html (which I don't think you'll need):

```html
<div class="row">
  <div [ngClass]="{'col-xs-12':isHidden === true, 'col-xs-7': isHidden !== false}" style="background-color:red;">
    <button class="form-control" style="width:150px;" (click)="toggleSummary()">Open Summary</button>
    <select id="empName" [(ngModel)]="selectedEmployee">
      <option selected="selected" disabled>Employee Name...</option>
      <option *ngFor="let emp of empInfo; let i = index" [ngValue]="i">{{i}} - {{emp.EmpID}}</option>
    </select>
    <select id="PTOtype">
      <option selected="selected" disabled>Type of PTO...</option>
      <option value="PTO">PTO</option>
      <option value="ETO-Earned">ETO - Earned</option>
      <option value="ETO-Used">ETO - Used</option>
      <option value="STDLTD">STD/LTD</option>
      <option value="Uncharged">Uncharged</option>
    </select>
    <button class="form-control" style="width: 150px;" (click)="nextEmployee()">Next</button>
    <button class="form-control" style="width: 150px;" (click)="previousEmployee()">Previous</button>
    <h2 *ngIf="empInfo && empInfo.length > selectedEmployee">{{empInfo[selectedEmployee].FirstName}} {{EmpKey}}</h2>
    <table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Date</th>
          <th>Full/Half</th>
          <th>Hours</th>
          <th>Scheduled?</th>
          <th>Notes</th>
          <th>In P/R?</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let pto of ptoData">
          <td>{{pto.date | date: 'MM/dd/y'}}</td>
          <td>{{pto.fullhalf}}</td>
          <td>{{pto.hours}}</td>
          <td>{{pto.scheduled}}</td>
          <td>{{pto.notes}}</td>
          <td>{{pto.inPR}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="isHidden" class="col-xs-5">
        <pto-summary [selectedEmployee]="selectedEmployee"></pto-summary>
  </div>
</div>
```

and then here's my array (which I also doubt you'll need):

```js
export class EmpInfo {
    EmpKey: number;
    EmpID: string;
    Firstname: string;
    LastName: string;
    EmpStat: string;
    StartDate: Date;
    AdjustedStart: Date;
    Anniversary: number;
    PTOYear: number;
    STDLTD: number;
    Uncharged: number;
    ETOEarned: number;
    ETORequests: number;
    ETORemaining: number;
    PTOBase: number;
    PTOCarry: number;
    PTOBorrowed: number;
    PTOBalance: number;
    PTORequests: number;
    PTORemaining: number;
}
```

Thanks in advance, your response means a lot from someone who's new to Angular!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, just look at your code:

```
empInfo: EmpInfo[];
```

so empInfo is not initialized to anything here. It's undefined

```
public selectedEmployee: number = 0;
public EmpKey: number = this.empInfo[this.selectedEmployee].EmpKey;
```

but here, you're trying to access its first element. Hence the error.

Comment: Yes, either you need to parse it differently, so as to return if the value is undefined, or you need to initiate to a value. Otherwise you'll end up with an 'undefined' error.

Comment: okay, that makes sense. How exactly would I go about doing that? I get the index of an item chosen from a combobox in tracker.component.html and set it to selectedEmployee. Then, I want to use that index to find that specified employees EmpKey which I am later going to use to filter items into a table

Comment: No problem, but don't do that until empInfo is initialized.

Comment: @JBNizet I did it as mentioned below in the other answer and it sort of does what I want it to do. It gets the EmpKey of the first person in the array but then if I change the person, it doesn't change the EmpKey. How could I fix this?

Comment: If you want to display the enmpKey of the selected employee in your view, then use `empInfo[this.selectedEmployee].EmpKey`in your view. If you store the EmpKey only once, at initialization time, then it will always have this same value, even if selectedEmployee changes.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to assign value EmpKey at declaration time. that causes the issue. try to assign value after getting employee data.

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { PTODataService } from './pto-data.service';
import { PTOData } from './pto-data';
import { EmpInfoService } from './emp-info.service';
import { EmpInfo } from './emp-info'; 

@Component({
    selector: 'pto-tracker',
    templateUrl: `./tracker.component.html`,
    styleUrls: ['./tracker.component.css']
})

export class TrackerComponent implements OnInit{
    empInfo: EmpInfo[];
    ptoData: PTOData[];
    isHidden: boolean = false;
    public selectedEmployee: number = 0;
    public EmpKey: number;

    constructor(
        private empInfoService: EmpInfoService,
        private ptoDataService: PTODataService) { }

    getEmpInfo(): void {
        this.empInfoService.getEmpInfos().then(
            empInfo => {
             this.empInfo = empInfo;
             this.EmpKey =  = this.empInfo[this.selectedEmployee].EmpKey
        });
    }

    getPTOData(): void {
        this.ptoDataService.getPTODatas().then(
            ptoData => this.ptoData = ptoData
        );
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.getEmpInfo();
        this.getPTOData();
    }

    toggleSummary(): void {
        this.isHidden = !this.isHidden;
    }

    nextEmployee(): void {
        this.selectedEmployee = this.selectedEmployee+1;
    }

    previousEmployee(): void {
        this.selectedEmployee = this.selectedEmployee-1;
    }
}
```

Comment: this sort of does what I want it to do. It gets the EmpKey of the first person in the array but then if I change the person, it doesn't change the EmpKey. How could I fix this?

Comment: in nextEmployee() metho you can update EmpKey. 
`this.EmpKey =  = this.empInfo[this.selectedEmployee].EmpKey`